# Comparing two column values with condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm wondering how to perform this algorithm in excel functions or vba code:

If ColA contain value from ColB and ColC is not 0.0, then copy values from ColB and Col C to ColE and ColF

Result should look like this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Dp_UeSLCh8mCfE9cirnA2ZlonLoYnKe9/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=114360056482069523351&rtpof=true&sd=true

Anyone could help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: By row? So in cell e1: if(and(a1=b1,c1<>0),b1,"") or similar - you can edit as needed.

Comment: No, rows might be not "side by side". They might be shuffled.

Comment: Then consider match(). Or look on here as there are examples already.

Comment: Column A doesn't contain value in C although there are some values which matches with Col B, therefore if you have access to O365 then you may try this formula, `=UNIQUE(FILTER(B$2:B$30,ISNUMBER(MATCH(B$2:B$30,$A$2:$A$30,0))))`